# on click event in JavaScript not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using jQuery sortable and have two two lists that I am moving items from one to another.  The first move works just fine with a double click.  Now that it is in the second list, I want to allow users to remove items by clicking and hitting the delete key.  My plan to do this is to have a click event trigger and decorate the list item with a class, and then when the delete key is hit, it will delete all items with that class.  At this point, I am having issues getting the click event to take hold.  Since I am creating the list items dynamic, I am using the on event keyword.  My html for the second list looks like this:

```
<div id="CartContents" class="ui-widget-content">
     <ul id="sortableArea" class="cartSortable">
     </ul>
</div>
```

My js for trying to handle the click event looks like this:

```
$('.cartSortable li').on("click", function () {
    alert('here');
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

The alert is there so that I know if it was hit.  Let me know what you think is wrong or where my understanding is lacking.

Comment: I dont see any li there..

Comment: Li's are lazy-loaded right?

Comment: Does your JavaScript code load at the top of the page or the bottom?

Comment: the li's are added dynamically.  I will update with the li in it. 

I was using the class on the ul not the id on the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating the list items dynamically, you need to [delegate the event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$('.cartSortable').on('click', 'li', function () {
```

Or, if your script is executed before the `<body>`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cartSortable li', function () {
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.  My quick understanding from reading the link you provided is that the event is binded to the div that exist on page load with a reference to the the li that will be created later.  Is this correct, or is there a better way to think about it?

Comment: You've got the right idea. The event is *delegated* to `.cartSortable`, which looks for a child `li` that was clicked. jQuery also changes `this` to point to the clicked `li` inside the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

you can use jQuery's `live` method which binds event handler to all elements that match current query selector.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('.cartSortable li').live("click", function () {
    alert('here');
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Live has been deprecated and removed from modern JQuery versions. 4+ years ago and this would have been a valid answer.